# Find row value, copy row and all the range underneath for data reduction

Tags: vba, excel, find, copy

I am trying to use a macro to clean up data files and only copy on Sheet2 what is most relevant.

I have written the code to find the row I want the data to be copied from. However I can only copy the row itself and not the range underneath. Please note I need the range to go from that row to the last column and last row as the size of the matriz always varies.

```
s            N      s           N       s           N      s            N       s       rpm
Linear      Real    Linear      Real    Linear      Real   Linear       Real    Linear  Amplitude
 0.0000030  9853.66 0.0000030   5951.83 0.0000030   533.48  0.0000030   476.15  0.0000030   2150.16
 0.0000226  9848.63 0.0000226   5948.19 0.0000226   557.02  0.0000226   488.60  0.0000226   2150.16
 0.0000421  9826.05 0.0000421   5956.22 0.0000421   615.94  0.0000421   480.75  0.0000421   2150.15
 0.0000616  9829.72 0.0000616   5989.72 0.0000616   642.59  0.0000616   476.77  0.0000616   2150.15
```

So basically the code below finds that first row and copies it in Sheet2. I need the macro to also select the range underneath and copy it onto Sheet2. Please can you help me finishing off the script?

```
Sub SearchForRawData()

Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

'Start search in row 1
LSearchRow = 1

'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
LCopyToRow = 2

While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) >= 0

  'If value in column A = "s", copy entire row to Sheet2
  If Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = "s" Then

     'Select row and range in Sheet1 to copy
     Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
     Selection.Copy

     'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
     Sheets("Sheet2").Select
     Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste

     'Select all Raw Data underneath found Row to Copy


     'Paste all Raw Data into Sheet 2


     'Move counter to next row
     LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

     'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
     Sheets("Sheet1").Select

   End If

   LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend

'Position on cell A1
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select

MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
  MsgBox "An error has occured"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this if you want to copy the row that has the "s" and everything below it to the target sheet. The following sub finds the row with the "s" in column A and then copies that row and everything below it to the target sheet.

Note that you should always avoid selecting or activating anything in VBA code, and that the normal way to copy and paste relies on selecting. If you use the syntax I've included here, the clipboard is not used and the target sheet does not need to be selected.

```
Sub CopyRowAndBelowToTarget()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim match As Range

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set src = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set tgt = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    Dim lastCopyRow As Long
    Dim lastPasteRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim matchRow As Long
    Dim findMe As String

    ' specify what we're searching for
    findMe = "s"

    ' find our search string in column A (1)
    Set match = src.Columns(1).Find(What:=findMe, After:=src.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    ' figure out what row our search string is on
    matchRow = match.Row

    ' get the last row and column with data so we know how much to copy
    lastCopyRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = src.Cells(1, src.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' find out where on our target sheet we should paste the results
    lastPasteRow = tgt.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' use copy/paste syntax that doesn't use the clipboard 
    ' and doesn't select or activate
    src.Range(Cells(matchRow, 1), Cells(lastCopyRow, lastCol)).Copy _
        tgt.Range("A" & lastPasteRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: Can't vote yet as I don't have enough reputation yet. That works beautifully. Thank you very much for your answers guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
```

So firstly you don't acutally need the `CStr`, vba will cast numbers to strings by itself, i.e. `Range(LSearchRow & ":" & LSearchRow)` should work fine.

To find  how many rows down to go use the `end` function of the `range` object:

```
bottomRow = Range("A" & LSearchRow).End(xldown).Row
```

Do the same for the column

```
lastCol = Range("A" & LSearchRow).End(xlleft).column
```

Now to copy:

```
Range("A" & LSearchRow & ":" & lastCol & bottomRow).Copy
```

However if you have empty cells inthe middleof the data then instead of using `End(xldown)`, start at the bottom of the sheet and look up:

```
bottomRow = Range("A1000000").End(xlup).Row
```

etc